# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Action::execute() /home/public_html/system/engine/event.php on line 62

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, opencart

Hi tried refreshing the modification cache cache in opencart and since then i am getting a blank page in front end with this error message.

```
public function trigger($event, array $args = array()) {
        foreach ($this->data as $value) {
            if (preg_match('/^' . str_replace(array('\*', '\?'), array('.*', '.'), preg_quote($value['trigger'], '/')) . '/', $event)) {
                $result = $value['action']->execute($this->registry, $args);

            if (!is_null($result) && !($result instanceof Exception)) {
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: public function trigger($event, array $args = array()) {
  foreach ($this->data as $value) {
   if (preg_match('/^' . str_replace(array('\*', '\?'), array('.*', '.'), preg_quote($value['trigger'], '/')) . '/', $event)) {
    $result = $value['action']->execute($this->registry, $args);

Comment: What error message?

Comment: Is this piece of phpMyAdmin application? Why is it tagged with it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your have an OC version 3.0.2.x or above.

In your `$this->data` of the Event Class, you have an event registered that is missing an action parameter.

```php
$this->data[] = array(
    'trigger'  => $trigger,
    'action'   => $action, // <-- this must be an Action Object with a method execute()
    'priority' => $priority
);
```

All events are registered via the `register()` method which explicitly requests that an Action object is being passed as a parameter.

Since the error is pointing to "Call to undefined method Action::execute()", I can assume, you have an issue with the action class.

Most likely you need to check the Modifications of the `system/engine/action.php` file in your `system/storage/modifications`.

It could be that the method `execute()` is either missing or somehow corrupt.

### Debug

try to var_dump the $value to see what is there:

```php
public function trigger($event, array $args = array()) {
        foreach ($this->data as $value) {
//log out the $value before the error to see if the Action object is actually there and see what trigger causes this.
var_dump($value);
            if (preg_match('/^' . str_replace(array('\*', '\?'), array('.*', '.'), preg_quote($value['trigger'], '/')) . '/', $event)) {
                $result = $value['action']->execute($this->registry, $args);

            if (!is_null($result) && !($result instanceof Exception)) {
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps